# Why does my code not move on from taking the specified number of inputs?

Tags: java

The code fragment I have attached is of a non-optimized method for bubble sorting.The problem I am facing is that the program keeps on taking inputs and doesn't go on to the function call in the main method.Would someone guide me as to what i should do to remove this anomaly from my code?

> Here is my Code:-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr){
        int i,j,t,n;
        n=arr.length;
        for (i=0;i<(n-1);++i){
            for (j=1;j<(n-i-1);++j){
                if(arr[i]>arr[i=1]){
                t=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=t;
                }
            }
        }
        printSortedArray(arr);
    }
    public static void printSortedArray(int[] arr){
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int j : arr) System.out.print(j + ",");
        System.out.print("}");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a range for array");
        n=a.nextInt();
        int [] b=new int[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
            b[i]=a.nextInt();
        bubbleSort(b);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `++i` to `i++`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works on my machine.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper That would not affect the behaviour of this code.

Comment: @luk2302.Wow...really?

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, I just tried it and it works for me too, with both `i++` and `++i`. Like luk2302, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: The problem is that your algorithm is buggy and you get into an infinite loop in the `bubbleSort(b)`.

Comment: You never use `j`, another bug making the sorting not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in this if (method bubbleSort) which causes an infinite loop.
Change:

```
if(arr[i]>arr[i=1]){
```

To:

```
if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
```

Comment: Yes, correct answer regarding the issue of never stopping, the algorithm is still broken though, but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @DestructiveGamer now please start debugging, adding breakpoints, `System.out.println(...)` statements etc. to understand why the code does still not work as expected.

Comment: Well, the question is a little wrong, the program does not take inputs infinitely, there is that typo which causes an infinite loop...and the algorithm is not really broken, just a little slower than an usual bubblesort, as the for with j could be optimized

Comment: no, the algo is broken, input a 5 as array length and then enter 5 4 3 2 1 and check the resulting array: `{4,3,2,5,1,}` is not very sorted

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just realized he was talking about bubble sort, not naive sort, and j is not used at all... He should delete the for with j and wrap the remaining for in a while that stops when no swaps are made when checking the whole array

Comment: @AndreiXwe...could you help me with that..I am unfortunately unable to understand what you are trying to say..

Comment: The way I learned bubble sort is that you should swap adjacent elements until the array is sorted. So, before each step (inside the while), you assume the array is sorted and if you make a swap, then you mark the array as not sorted so you loop at least one more time:
boolean sorted = false;
        while (! sorted) {
         sorted = true;
         for (i=0;i<(n-1);++i){
                if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                 t=arr[i];
                 arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                 arr[i+1]=t;
                 sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: But why do you set sorted as false in the inner if?

Comment: because if we swap two elements, it means the array is not sorted, so we have to loop through it at least one more time, so the while continues